# Как передать класс унаследованный от List в Get запросе?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Я хочу создать класс Page, с которым смогу работать как с коллекцией и в Get запросе получать его в следующем виде:

```
{
    "items": [],
    "pageSize": 100,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "lastPage": true
}
```

Технически это просто List с дополнительной информацией. Попробовал создать класс унаследованный от List:

```
[DataContract]
public class Page<T> : List<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Items
    {
        get => this;
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                AddRange(value);
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool LastPage { get; set; }
}
```

Что я получаю в запросе:

```
[]
```

Нужный мне результат возвращается при композиции:

```
[DataContract]
public class Page<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; } = new List<T>();

    [DataMember]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool LastPage { get; set; }
}
```

Но композиция это не то что я хотел. Как мне настроить сериализацию для первой реализации?

Comment: 1) Зачем вам это, зачем такое наследование кривое? 2) просто уберите наследование и готово, используйте свойство 3) DataContract устарел и умер когда я ещё был маленьким, используйте System.Text.Json и уберите эти страшные аттрибуты

Comment: Зачем вы создали свойство `List<T> Items`? Ведь после того, как вы уснаследовались `Page<T> : List<T>`, ваш класс уже является коллекцией, у него есть индексатор и всё прочее необходимое. Просто добавьте данные в него перед сериализацией.

Comment: @aepot я понимаю что могу использовать свойство. Я хочу узнать есть ли возможность работать с Page напрямую как с коллекцией и настроить сериализацию/десереализацию как мне будет удобно (первый пример)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сериализатор игнорировал свойства которые я добавил и я предположил, что ему нужно отдельное свойство под коллекцию

Comment: Какой сериализатор?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я передаю страницу в ObjectResult, а он в свою очередь использует библиотеку System.Text.Json, если я правильно понял

Comment: Тогда на кой чёрт атрибуты `DataContract` и `DataMember`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov где то увидел что они могут помочь, но что с ними, что без них, результат одинаковый. Я от них избавлюсь